# If-else statement in in for is_displayed() in Appium Python

Tags: python, xpath, appium

I am trying to automate mobile testing using Appium and Python. I need to check if an element is displayed and perform some actions and perform some another actions if the element is not displayed. My script is as bellow;

```
      wifi = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"android.widget.TextView") and contains(@text, "WLAN")]')


    if wifi.is_displayed():
            print 'Wifi is switched off'
            mobiledata = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, "Mobile data")]')
            mobiledata.click()

            print 'SUCCESS! Switch on Mobile data'

    else:
            print 'Wifi is switched on'

            wifi_off = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"android.view.ImageView") and contains(@index, "0")]')
            wifi_off.click()
            print 'SUCCESS! Switch off Wifi'
            mobiledata = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text, "Mobile data")]')
            mobiledata.click()

            print 'SUCCESS! Switch on Mobile data'
```

Now the problem I'm facing is that when the if condition is true the script is running well, but when it is false it gives the error that element "wifi" could not be found (which is true, but that's why I need to move to the else part.

How can I fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between whether an element exists and whether an element is displayed - when an element isn't found then an exception is thrown by `driver.find_element_by_xxx`

If you want to check whether an element exists, then you're better to do `driver.find_elements_by_xxx` as it will return an empty list rather than throw an exception if no elements match the search criteria.

So you can change your code to something like:

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(blah)
wifi = None if len(elements) == 0 else elements[0]
if wifi and wifi.is_displayed():
    blah
else:
    blah
```